# Spark: How to get probabilities and AUC for Bernoulli Naive Bayes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes, apache-spark-ml

I'm running a `Bernoulli Naive Bayes` using code:

```
val splits = MyData.randomSplit(Array(0.75, 0.25), seed = 2L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)
val model = NaiveBayes.train(training, lambda = 3.0, modelType = "bernoulli")
```

My question is how can I get the probability of membership to class 0 (or 1) and count AUC. I want to get similar result to `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` or `SVMWithSGD` where I was using this code:

```
val numIterations = 100

val model = SVMWithSGD.train(training, numIterations)
model.clearThreshold()

// Compute raw scores on the test set.
val labelAndPreds = test.map { point =>
      val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
      (prediction, point.label)
}

// Get evaluation metrics.
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(labelAndPreds)
val auROC = metrics.areaUnderROC()
```

Unfortunately this code isn't working for `NaiveBayes`.

Comment: Ok this is a 2-in-1 question. So which version of spark are you using? Also you want probabilities for what?

Comment: Spark 1.5.0. I want `P(Y=0|X)`, having this I'll be able to count AUC, am I right?

Comment: Yes it's a binary classification

Comment: I'm using spark.mllib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning the probabilities for Bernouilli Naive Bayes, here is an example :

```scala
// Building dummy data
val data = sc.parallelize(List("0,1 0 0", "1,0 1 0", "1,0 0 1", "0,1 0 1","1,1 1 0"))

// Transforming dummy data into LabeledPoint
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
}

// Prepare data for training
val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.75, 0.25), seed = 2L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)
val model = NaiveBayes.train(training, lambda = 3.0, modelType = "bernoulli")

// labels 
val labels = model.labels
// Probabilities for all feature vectors
val features = parsedData.map(lp => lp.features)
model.predictProbabilities(features).take(10) foreach println

// For one specific vector, I'm taking the first vector in the parsedData
val testVector = parsedData.first.features
println(s"For vector ${testVector} => probability : ${model.predictProbabilities(testVector)}")
```

As for the AUC :

```
// Compute raw scores on the test set.
val labelAndPreds = test.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (prediction, point.label)
}

// Get evaluation metrics.
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(labelAndPreds)
val auROC = metrics.areaUnderROC()
```

Concerning the inquiry from the chat :

```scala
val results = parsedData.map { lp =>
  val probs: Vector = model.predictProbabilities(lp.features)
  (for (i <- 0 to (probs.size - 1)) yield ((lp.label, labels(i), probs(i))))
}.flatMap(identity)

results.take(10).foreach(println)

// (0.0,0.0,0.59728640251696)
// (0.0,1.0,0.40271359748304003)
// (1.0,0.0,0.2546873180388961)
// (1.0,1.0,0.745312681961104)
// (1.0,0.0,0.47086939671877026)
// (1.0,1.0,0.5291306032812298)
// (0.0,0.0,0.6496075621805428)
// (0.0,1.0,0.3503924378194571)
// (1.0,0.0,0.4158585282373076)
// (1.0,1.0,0.5841414717626924)
```

and if you are only interested in the argmax classes :

```scala
val results = training.map { lp => val probs: Vector = model.predictProbabilities(lp.features)
  val bestClass = probs.argmax
  (labels(bestClass), probs(bestClass))
}
results.take(10) foreach println

// (0.0,0.59728640251696)
// (1.0,0.745312681961104)
// (1.0,0.5291306032812298)
// (0.0,0.6496075621805428)
// (1.0,0.5841414717626924)
```

**Note:** Works with **Spark 1.5+**

**EDIT: (for Pyspark users)**

It seems like some are having troubles getting probabilities using **pyspark** and **mllib**. Well that's normal, **spark-mllib** doesn't present that function for pyspark.

Thus you'll need to use the **spark-ml** `DataFrame`-based API :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayes

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0])),
    Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0])),
    Row(label=1.0, features=Vectors.dense([1.0, 0.0]))])

nb = NaiveBayes(smoothing=1.0, modelType="bernoulli")
model = nb.fit(df)

model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)
# +---------+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
# |features |label|rawPrediction                            |probability                             |prediction|
# +---------+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
# |[0.0,0.0]|0.0  |[-1.4916548767777167,-2.420368128650429] |[0.7168141592920354,0.28318584070796465]|0.0       |
# |[0.0,1.0]|0.0  |[-1.4916548767777167,-3.1135153092103742]|[0.8350515463917526,0.16494845360824742]|0.0       |
# |[1.0,0.0]|1.0  |[-2.5902671654458262,-1.7272209480904837]|[0.29670329670329676,0.7032967032967034]|1.0       |
# +---------+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

You'll just need to select your *prediction* column and compute your AUC.

For more information about Naive Bayes in spark-ml, please refer to the official documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes).

Comment: Thank you very much! I change it a little bit and now I can get `(label,P(y=0|x))`:                   

`val results = test.map { lp =>
  val probs: Vector = model.predictProbabilities(lp.features)
  val MyList = List.range(0,(probs.size - 1),2)
  (for (i <- MyList) yield ((lp.label, probs(i))))
}.flatMap(identity)`